# Implementing Azure Communication Services - Chat in Android application

Tags: android, azure, azure-communication-services

I'm trying to implement Chat functionality in the Android app using **Azure Communication Services (Chat)**. I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?pivots=programming-language-android this link to set up the Android project. Inside the Android app, we need few configuration data of Azure communication resources like,

```java
String endpoint = "https://<resource>.communication.azure.com";
String firstUserId = "<first_user_id>";
String secondUserId = "<second_user_id>";
String firstUserAccessToken = "<first_user_access_token>";
```

After going through Microsoft doc, I found this link [Access Token Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/access-tokens?pivots=programming-language-csharp), a console application for creating **Identity.ID** and **Access Token**. And I used the same access token and Identity.ID which was generated by console application for FirstUserAccessToken and First UserID. Once this is done I ran the Android app, but I got a Null pointer exception while calling

```java
CreateChatThreadResult createChatThreadResult = chatAsyncClient.createChatThread(createChatThreadOptions).get();
```

On calling **.get** app throws a exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.azure.android.core.http.HttpResponse.getStatusCode()' on a null object reference

First place, want to know whether the **AccessToken** and **UserId** that I'm using are correct or not.

Am I missing something here? Or is there any server-side setup to be done for the same?

Answer (score 0):

> First place, want to know whether the AccessToken and UserId that I'm using are correct or not.

Yes, using the `CommunicationIdentityClient` to create a user and issue a token is the right approach. Just make sure you specify the right scope. This example [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?pivots=programming-language-android#prerequisites) setting the `CHAT` scope.

```java
List<CommunicationTokenScope> scopes = Arrays.asList(CommunicationTokenScope.CHAT);
CommunicationUserIdentifierAndToken result = communicationIdentityClient.createUserAndToken(scopes);
```

Recently, there's been a new option added to [quickly generate Azure Communication Services access tokens for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/identity/quick-create-identity) - you can do it directly in the Azure Portal.

I just quickly tried the [finalized sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-android-quickstarts/tree/main/Add-chat) from GitHub and it worked flawlessly. The steps I took:

- installed Android Studio + Android 11 SDK (API level 30)
- created a Pixel 4 device running Android 11
- cloned the [repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-android-quickstarts/tree/main/Add-chat)
- replaced the `endpoint`, `firstUserId`, `secondUserId`, `firstUserAccessToken` with values generated in the Azure Portal
- ran the sample + successfully debugged it

[image: Debugging chat sample app for android]